# Move position of math symbols in natural deduction rule

Tags: math-mode, positioning, logic

Writting this LaTex code

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\debox}[1]{\boxed{\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}}_{\strut}\hspace{0.1cm}}

\[
\dfrac{\phi \lor \psi \qquad \debox{\phi \\ \vdots \\ \chi} \debox{\psi \\ \vdots \\ \chi}}{\chi}
\]
\end{document}
```

results in the following output:

[image]

Is it possible to move the position of the logical disjunction such that it is just above the horizontal line instead of having this big vertical space?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\newcommand{\debox}[1]{\boxed{\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}}_{\strut}\hspace{0.1cm}}

\begin{document}

\[
\dfrac{\phi \raisebox{-5.5ex}{$\mathrlap{ \lor }$}\mathrel{\vphantom{\lor}} \psi \qquad \debox{\phi \\ \vdots \\ \chi} \debox{\psi \\ \vdots \\ \chi}}{\chi}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I do wonder why you are making life hard for yourself re-inventing the wheel, when there are a number of very good packages for setting natural deduction proofs?

Look at the Latex for Logicians pages, particularly https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/